# how to save the selected date in the database

Tags: android, database, datepicker

I am trying to save the selected date in the database.
 I did that with the help of date picker, now i need to save it in the database.
How to do that? How to get the selected date and store it in the database? Can any one help to me?

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startdate=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
            int dayOfMonth) { 
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear); 
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);                 
    } 
};  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtask);       

        Button startbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AddStartButton);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                new DatePickerDialog(AddTask.this,startdate, 
                        dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                        dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                        dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();             
                } 

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startdate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // onDateSet method
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"+String.valueOf(year);
            Toast.makeText(AddTask.this, "Selected start Date is "+date_selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            };
```

Thank you.

Comment: see this [link](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this link ezhil

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/1/

it will help full for learn database

Add two buttons like Save and cancel

if U click Save button u have to store the date in database

if u click cancel don't save it..